# Function DLookup in Ms Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

[image: This code]

gives me

[image: this error]

when saving records in the system.

Can anyone let me know what is the problem in this?

```
xx = DLookup("[part_number]", "tblModelCost", "[Customer_ID]= " & me.Customer_ID & " and [Model] = '" & me.[txtModel] & "' and [Description] = 'screen'")
```

Comment: That's way too much code to run in the _OnChange_ event. Try moving it to the _AfterUpdate_ event.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Me.Customer_Id should be Me!Customer_Id.  However, that depends on the form control name and what you are trying to do.  Assuming you have a control named "Customer_ID" and a field named "Customer_ID" Me.Customer_ID will try to use the  the control value, me!Customer_ID will try to use the underlying bound field value.  If you don't have a control named Customer_ID then using Me.Customer_ID will cause the error you are getting.  (This is why you want to learn to use controls names like txtCustomer_ID for your controls.  )